# ^[\p{L}\p{N}]{1,50}$ >>> plus one rule

Tags: regex

I've this regex: `^[\p{L}\p{N}]{1,50}$`

- Accept all numbers and all letters
- min length: 1
- max length: 50

I'm trying to add this rule without success:

- can add \s (spaces) but the text can not have only empty spaces

Comment: the space supposed to be in the middle of the string or could it be at the start/end?

Comment: Which implementation of regex are you using?  Perl, Python, XML schema?

Comment: @SilentGhost: You're right, I read the feature table wrong. :)  http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your regular expression implementation supports [look-ahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!\s+$)[\p{L}\p{N}\s]{1,50}$
```

Comment: Might not be, though.  Need the OP to clarify.

Comment: @Adam Bellaire: There are many regular expression implementations that support Unicode character properties. But as far as I know, in you don’t specify the start and end in XML as it always matches the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it can't start with a space:

```
^[\p{L}\p{N}]{1}[\s\p{L}\p{N}]{0,49}$
```

Answer (score 0):

allow it and then trim double+ spaces